# Permutation & Combination - how many numbers smaller than $2.10^8$ and are divisible by $3$ can be written by means of the digits $0$,$1$ and $2$

Tags: combinatorics

How many numbers smaller than $2\times10^8$ and divisible by $3$ can be written by means of the digits $0$,$1$ and $2$?
Left zero padding not allowed.

I am getting this as -
$3$ digits - $2\cdot3 = 6$
$4$ digits - $2\cdot3\cdot3 = 18$
$5$ digits - $2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3 = 54$
$6$ digits - $2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3 = 162$
$7$ digits - $2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3 = 486$
$8$ digits - $2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3 = 1458$

From $10^8$ to $2\times10^8$ - $2\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3
\cdot3\cdot3/2 = 2187$

I get $4371$ as the answer, but in the book the result is $4351$, am I making an error somewhere?

Comment: What is meant by zero padding? Padding on left, right, or even in between the other digits?

Comment: Zeros on left... Not allowed.

Comment: Total number of numbers divisible by $3$ is $2.10^8/3$. Now we need to count only the numbers whose digit are $0,1,2 $

Answer (score 3):

We solve the simpler problem of counting the numbers from $0$ to $10^8-1$ of the right shape that are divisible by $3$. We do allow zero padding to make all the numbers into $8$-digit numbers. This makes **no** difference to the count.

The same method works for the other half of our interval.

We use a general approach, though the particular case is too simple and quickly collapses. One could then in hindsight give a slicker argument, but we won't do that.

Let $a(n)$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers that use only $0$, $1$, and $2$ and are divisible by $3$. Let $b(n)$ be the number of $n$-digit numbers, of the right form, that give remainder $1$ on division by $3$, and let $c(n)$ be the same thing, except for remainder $2$. We have $a(1)=b(1)=c(1)=1$. Note that
$$a(n+1)=a(n)+b(n)+c(n).$$
This is because a qualifying $n+1$ digit number can be obtained by appending a $0$ to an $n$-digit number divisible by $3$, or a $2$ to an $n$-digit number that has remainder $1$, or a $1$ to an $n$-digit number that has remainder $2$. Similarly, we have $b(n)=a(n)+b(n)+c(n)$ and $c(n)=a(n)+b(n)+c(n)$.

It follows that $a(2)=b(2)=c(2)=3$, and $a(3)=b(3)=c(3)=9$, and so on. Thus $a(8)=3^7$.

For the numbers from $1\times 10^8$ to $2\times 10^8-1$, do the same calculation for numbers of the form $1x$, where $x$ is a (padded) $8$-digit number.

Comment: I am getting this as - 
3 digits - 2*3 = 6
4 digits - 2*3*3 = 18
5 digits - 2*3*3*3 = 54
6 digits - 2*3*3*3*3 = 162
7 digits - 2*3*3*3*3*3*3 = 486
8 digits - 2*3*3*3*3*3*3*3 = 1458
From 1*10^8 to 2*10^8 - 2*3*3*3*3*3*3*3*3/2 = 2187

I get 4371 as the answer, but in book this show 4351, am I making an Error somewhere. Please help!!
Thanks.

Comment: Will get back to you, probably not for half day or so, sleep, then busy half-day.

Comment: Checked again. from $0$ to $2\times 10^8$, have $2\times 3^7$. Take away $1$ if we don't want to count $0$. Your counts are correct, bur left out the $2$ digit $12$ and $21$, and (subject to interpretation) the $1$-digit number $0$. So $4373$ or $4374$, depending on interpretation. I do not see anything that we can discard that would lead to $4351$.